# box model with anchor and button

Tags: html, css

I have the following fiddle: **[My Button Bar](http://jsfiddle.net/m2DJX/)**

My problem is a common one, though inline-block is not helping like I hoped. How do I make the anchor and the button the same size. The blue buttons need to be contained within the gray bar, they should have a small border, and be the same size, as you would **totally expect** from a **button bar**.

It only really has to work in firefox and chrome. We are not bothering with IE anymore (*Chrome Frame*).

**The html looks like this:**

```
<div class="buttons">
    <button class="inline-button" type="submit" name="action" value="Update"><span data-icon="icon-cog">icon</span>Save</button>
    <a href="#"><span data-icon="icon-cog">icon</span>Cancel</a>
</div>
```

**The CSS I am using is as follows:**

```
div.buttons a, div.buttons button[type=submit] {
  position: static;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -ms-border-radius: 4px;
  -o-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  outline: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: PTSansBold;
  font-size: 12pt;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #051DC3;
  color: white;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 3px;
  width: 8em;
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m2DJX/3/)***

**Hi now try this css** This is **Css3** `Box-sizing : border-box`

```
div.buttons a, div.buttons button[type="submit"]{
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

### ***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m2DJX/3/)***

---

***[more about this box-sizing](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)***

Answer (score 0):

```
 <button class="inline-button" type="submit" name="action" value="Update"><span data-icon="icon-cog">icon</span>Save</button>
<button class="inline-button" type="submit" name="action" value="Update"><span data-icon="icon-cog">icon</span>Cancel</button>
```

You have not used the button tag for the second button. It works perfectly by adding this

Comment: the point of the question is understand how to style the anchor and the button the same.

Comment: but you could use the button and make it the same. It serves the purpose right ?

Comment: It doesn't really no. An anchor tag is a link to another action and issues an HTTP "GET". A button submits to an action handler and issues an HTTP "POST". They are completely different.